# SyntaxError in BookmkfoldersController#index, unknown regexp options - dv

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make an web application, and everything's been working fine so far. However, ActionView is suddenly wrong. It seems it can't recognize closed html tags. Every time it sees a closed parentheses, it claims that these are unclosed. However, I think they all are! I've posted the error log below, probably someone knows what's going on...!

I get following error :

```
 SyntaxError in BookmkfoldersController#index
 app/views/bookmkfolders/index.html.erb:16: unknown regexp options - dv
 app/views/bookmkfolders/index.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

and this is file `index.html.erb`

```
<ul class="board-canvas" data-update-url = "<%=sort_bookmkfolders_url %>">

 <% @bookmkfolders.each do |bookmkfolder| %>
      <div class="panel-wrapped">
          <li id="<%=bookmkfolder.id%>" class="panel" style = "background-color:<%=bookmkfolder.bookmkfoldercolor%>">
            <%= text_field_tag :test, "", class: 'thVal' %>
            <h2 class= "panel-title" ><%= bookmkfolder.bookmkfoldertitle %></h2>
            <div class="panel-menu">
              <%= button_tag "Add a bookmark-url", type: 'button', class: 'addfolder js-add-card' %>
              <div class="add-card-form">
                <%= simple_form_for @bookmkfolder, remote: true, url: {action: "<%= @bookmkfolder.id %>"} do |k| %>
                <%= k.input_field :bookmktitle, class: 'board-make-input', autocomplete: :off, autocorrect: :off, spellcheck: false, placeholder: 'Add a bookmark' %>
                <%= button_tag "SAVE", type: 'submit' , class: 'save-button js-save-card' %>
                <%= button_tag "", type: 'button', class: 'delete-button' , "<span class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>".html_safe %>
                <% end %>
              </div>   # this is error message app/views/bookmkfolders/index.html.erb:16
            </div>
          </li>

          <ul class="card-list">
            <% bookmkfolder.@bookmks.each do |bookmk| %>
              <li class ="card-item">
                <%= link_to "","<%= bookmk.bookmktitle %>", class: 'card-link' %>
                <%= image_tag "#", class: 'card-thumbnail' %>
                <p class = "card-txt"><%= bookmk.bookmktitle%></p>
              </li>
            <%end%>
          </ul>
      </div>
 <%end%>
</ul>
```

and this is extracted sources from `bookmkfolders_controller`.

```
def index
 @bookmkfolders = Bookmkfolder.all
 @bookmkfolders = Bookmkfolder.order("sequence")
 @bookmkfolder = Bookmkfolder.new
 @bookmks = Bookmk.all
 @bookmk = Bookmk.new
end

def newfolder

 #  redirect_to '/bookmkfolder/createfolder'
end

def createfolder
 colors = ['#c9ddff', '#c9ffdd', '#ffd2c9', '#c9caff', '#fdc9ff', '#fffdc9', 
 '#c9fffc', '#ffc9c9', '#ffe5c9', '#eaffc9']
  puts Bookmkfolder.methods
  @bookmkfolder = Bookmkfolder.new(bookmkfolder_params)
  @bookmkfolder.user = current_user
  @bookmkfolder.sequence = Bookmkfolder.count + 1
  @bookmkfolder.bookmkfoldercolor = colors.at(rand(colors.size))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bookmkfolder.save
      format.html { redirect_to @bookmkfolder, notice: 'Bookmkfolder was 
successfully created.' }
      format.js {}
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bookmkfolder }

    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @bookmkfolder.errors, status: 
   :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest `<% %>` like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @bookmkfolder, remote: true, url: {action: "<%= @bookmkfolder.id %>"} do |k| %>
```

Once you open a `<%` you are using Ruby, so you can just use the variables in the code, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @bookmkfolder, remote: true, url: { action: @bookmkfolder.id } do |k| %>
```

---

Not related to current error, but also notice that the second `button_tag` is incorrect (aside from using nested double quotes), you can't pass an argument like you are trying to do with `"<span>...</span>".html_safe`.

What you are looking for is to pass a *block*, like this:

```
<div class="add-card-form">
  <%= button_tag "", type: 'button', class: 'delete-button' do %>
    <span class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You can read about `button_tag` in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag).

Comment: Thanks for anwsering but it didn't work... I edited to codes you taught but I got same error message.

Comment: @SeanHuh Check updated answer, i missed some error in `simple_form_for`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong:

`<%= button_tag "", type: 'button', class: 'delete-button' , "<span class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>".html_safe %>`

You're trying to enclose `"<span class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>"` in a weird way.

This should work:

`'<span class="fa fa-times fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></span>'`

(i replaced the start and end " with ')

Comment: Thanks for anwsering but it didn't work...  I got same error message.                    Even I delete that code you mention, I got an new error message (c:/Ruby22-x64/DevKit/git/bookmarker/app/views/bookmkfolders/index.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected '<')   which means a code under the previous error code.